# Java Generics Capture

Tags: java

I have some code like this.
Payload is Java object.

*DSRecommendations and LsRecommendations extends RecEntry*

*objectMapper and TypeReference are from jackson and RecEntry is my own class*

*payload is just a list of recEntry*

```
public enum RecSourceEnum {
    CSELL(DSRecommendations.class),
    LS(LsRecommendations.class);

    private final Class<? extends RecEntry> recEntry;

    <T extends RecEntry> RecSourceEnum(Class<T> recEntry) {
        this.recEntry = recEntry;
    }

    public Class<? extends RecEntry> getRecEntry() {
        return recEntry;
    }
}

    String source = "CSELL";
    Class<? extends RecEntry> clazz = RecSourceEnum.valueOf(source.toUpperCase()).getRecEntry();
                List<RecEntry> recommEntryList = convertFromObj(payload, clazz);

    private static <T extends RecEntry> List<T> convertFromObj(Object payload, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
            TypeReference<List<T>> mapType = new TypeReference<List<T>>() {};
            return objectMapper.convertValue(payload, mapType);
        }
```

When I try to run this code. I get this error.

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Class<? extends entry.RecEntry>', required: 'java.lang.Class<T>' less... 

convertFromObj
(Object, java.lang.Class<T>)
in BManagerImpl cannot be applied to
(Object, java.lang.Class<capture<? extends entry.RecEntry>>)
 
 reason: Incompatible equality constraint: RecEntry and capture of ? extends RecEntry
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You have a `List<X>` and you want to assign a `List<Y>` to it. The fact that there is inheritance between X and Y doesn't imply there is inheritance between `List<X>` and `List<Y>`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is actually what you are asking for, but I decided to post my answer anyway.

**Main Class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String source = "CSELL";
    Class<? extends Alphabet> clazz = RecSourceEnum.valueOf(source.toUpperCase()).getRecEntry();

    Alphabet abc = new Alphabet();

    Alphabet val = convertFromObj(abc, clazz);

    System.out.println(clazz);
    System.out.println("A: " + val.getClass());
}   

private static <T extends Alphabet> T convertFromObj(Object payload, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    return om.convertValue(payload, clazz);
}
```

**RecSourceEnum**

```
enum RecSourceEnum {
    CSELL(A.class),
    LS(B.class);

    private final Class<? extends Alphabet> recEntry;

    <T extends Alphabet> RecSourceEnum(Class<T> recEntry) {
        this.recEntry = recEntry;
    }

    public Class<? extends Alphabet> getRecEntry() {
        return recEntry;
    }
}
```

**Test classes**

```
class Alphabet{
    public String name;
}

class A extends Alphabet{
}

class B extends Alphabet{
}
```

**Output**

```
class test.A
A: class test.A
```